# launch sublime text 3 in terminal with zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I recently purchased a new MacBook and I am trying to re-configure my system.

The app is inside the Applications folder as 'Sublime Text.app'

I have edited the sublime.plugin.zsh file via other advice I found online to 'Sublime Text 3.app' as well as 'Sublime Text.app' with no luck on either:

```
elif  [[ $('uname') == 'Darwin' ]]; then
local _sublime_darwin_paths > /dev/null 2>&1
_sublime_darwin_paths=(
    "/usr/local/bin/subl"
    "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    "$HOME/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    "$HOME/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    "$HOME/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
)

for _sublime_path in $_sublime_darwin_paths; do
    if [[ -a $_sublime_path ]]; then
        alias subl="'$_sublime_path'"
        alias st=subl
        break
    fi
done
fi

alias stt='st .'
```

I still get

```
zsh: command not found: st
```

I am simply at a loss on where to go next

Comment: Does `apropos sublime` turn up anything useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try to first launch the sublime binary manually (interactively) via zsh.

To do that, you'll have to discover where this binary is. There are two practical options here, choose what you are most comfortable with:

1. Check manually those listed binaries, see which of them exist.
2. Slightly modify your script to `echo` something inside your `if`:

   ```
   if [[ -a $_sublime_path ]]; then
       echo "Sublime found: $_sublime_path"
       alias subl="'$_sublime_path'"
       alias st=subl
       break
   fi
   ```

After finding the correct one, create the `st` alias in your `.zshrc` file:

```
alias st="/correct/path/to/subl"
```

If you don't find anything in the first step, then your original script is really not supposed to work.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with zsh and this did the job:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Then you launch a open a file my_file.txt with Sublime:

```
subl ./my_file.txt
```

Don't specify any file if you just want to open Sublime. I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

To setup alias for mac users;

open `~/.zshrc` using the below command

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following alias

`alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"`

run `subl .` command should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just moved to App in mac
2. Check your current path

```
echo $PATH
```

3. Add a sym link from Sublime App to one of your path. Choose `/usr/local/bin` for example

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

4. Then back to terminal and run `sublime`. You should be open the sublime through terminal

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#mac

> ZSH
> If using Zsh, the default starting with macOS 10.15, the following command will add the bin folder to the PATH environment variable:
> `echo 'export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile`