# Hyper Terminal: zsh: command not found: hyper

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I am using hyper terminal. I wrote the following code to change the theme, but it gave the following error.

Command to change theme: hyper i verminal

> zsh: command not found: hyper

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By putting the directory, where `hyper` is stored, into the `path` array.

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem too. After some tinkering, this command worked for me (assuming you have the hyper app in the mac applications folder):

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Hyper.app/Contents/Resources/bin/hyper" /usr/local/bin/hyper
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60173558) from another question about how to get Sublime Text's zsh command working.

Answer (score 5):

On macOS Monterey the way to install new themes is to click on Tools at the menu bar in Hyper, then Install Hyper CLI command in PATH, then it will allow you to install said theme from the Hyper website such as "hyper i verminal", you will then see a message saying that verminal has been installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS simply navigate the toolbar: Plugins > Install Hyper CLI command in PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add its **bin** path to *system variable*. And then install the themes. Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).